# Repainting of chessboard with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, contest-math

> Assume an $8\times 8$ chessboard with the usual coloring. You may
> repaint all squares (a) of a row  or column  (b) of a $2\times 2$
> square. The goal is to attain one black square. Can you reach the
> goal?

I am not asking for the solution because I did not understand the problem properly. Below you see the picture of chessboard with usual coloring. Each  row and column has $4$ black and $4$ white squares. If you take any row (or column) and you repaint all squares you still get the row (or column) with $4$ black and $4$ white squares. Any $2\times 2$ square has $2$ black and $2$ white squares and after repainting the number of black and white squares remain unchanged.

Am I missing something? I'd be very thankful if someone can clarify the problem.
Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: You cannot change the number of black squares on your first move, but you can change the number of black squares with your second move.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, how come? can you explain it please?

Comment: Think about it, draw some pictures. For problem (a), the reason your first move cannot change the number of squares is that every row and column has four black squares. But after your first move, some rows/columns will have five black and three white squares.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, Thank you for your advice! I think that I understood what you meant and I even solved the question. Can you take a look is it correct? I tried to add details as much as possible since I am trying to improve my proof writing skills. Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: @MikeEarnest, can you take a look at my solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_i$ and $w_i$ are the number of black and white squares on the chessboard after $i$th step of repainting. Easy to see that $b_i+w_i=64$ with $(b_0,w_0)=(b_1,w_1)=(32,32)$.

Let's consider the following two cases:

**i)** If we apply repainting of type b) on the $(i+1)$th  step, then the following cases are possible: $(b_{i+1},w_{i+1})=(b_{i},w_{i}),\ (b_{i}\pm 2,w_{i}\mp 2),\ (b_{i}\pm 4,w_{i}\mp 4)$ depending on how many black cells $2\times 2$ square has. It follows that $b_{i+1}-w_{i+1}\equiv b_i-w_i \pmod 4$.

**ii)** If we apply repainting of type a) on the $(i+1)$th step, then we'll get the following situation: WLOG assume that we are repainting column with $x$ black and $y$ white cells. Except that column the chessboard has $b_i-x$ black and $w_i-y$ white cells. Then $(b_i,w_i)\to (b_i-x+y,w_i-y+x)=(b_{i+1},w_{i+1})$. Therefore,
$b_{i+1}-w_{i+1}=(b_i-w_i)-2(x-y)$. Since $x+y=8$, then $2\mid x-y$ and $b_{i+1}-w_{i+1}\equiv b_i-w_i \pmod 4$.

Therefore we were able to show that $b_{i+1}-w_{i+1}\equiv b_i-w_i \pmod 4$.

If it was possible to reach goal, then after $k$th step we would have $(b_k,w_k)=(1,63)$. Since $(b_0,w_0)=(32,32)$ then our claim implies that $b_k-w_k\equiv b_0-w_0\pmod 4$ which is the same as $1-63\equiv 32-32 \pmod 4$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $0\equiv 62\pmod 4$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: looks correct :^)